# Logging from other threads in Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, slf4j

Working with Google Cloud Dataflow, I've come across some strange behaviour. From within `Runnable`/`Callable`/etc instances executing in other threads, none of the logging output shows in the Stackdriver console. Testing the same code using the "direct runner," the expected logging occurs just fine.

I can't see any documentation to suggest logging from other threads *shouldn't* work, is this something not supported by Dataflow? If it is supported, how does one go about using it, or what might I be doing wrong?

Code example (warning: spews a bunch of lines to console):

`TestApp.java`

```
package myapp;

import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;

// basic pipeline setup...
public class TestApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();

    final Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    p.apply(TextIO.read().from("gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/*"))
      .apply("Processing", new TestAppProcess());

    p.run();
  }
}
```

`TestAppProcess.java`

```
package myapp;

import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;

public class TestAppProcess extends PTransform<PCollection<String>, PCollection<String>> {
  private static class ProcessFn extends DoFn<String, String> {
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger log =
      org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestAppProcess.class);

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext pc) throws InterruptedException {
      // This appears when using direct-runner
      // This appears in the Stackdriver console
      Runnable r1 = () -> log.info("Hello world from r1");
      r1.run();

      // This appears when using direct-runner
      // This DOESN'T appear in the Stackdriver console
      Runnable r2 = () -> log.info("Hello world from r2");
      Thread t = new Thread(r2);

      t.start();
      t.join();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public PCollection<String> expand(PCollection<String> input) {
    return input.apply(ParDo.of(new ProcessFn()));
  }
}
```

Comment: That's sketchy. I'll do a bit of research on it.

Comment: Hi @Murray. I take it that you didn't see the log on stackdriver, right? Did you try opening up the 'all logs' category, to see if they may have been mislabeled when going into stackdriver?

Comment: Correct @Pablo (I think). Some screenshots: https://i.imgur.com/n2Waqnn.png https://i.imgur.com/xjaWyNu.png 

I ended up passing loggable strings/timestamps to the main thread, hence the "Dumping cached..." part, which synchronously dumps everything after the other threads have joined (pretty useless, since it has to wait for every thread to join before outputting the logs; still, better than nothing). The other threads still call `log.whatever`, to no effect.